# Slow query with multiple INNER JOIN (via table)

Tags: mysql, join

This is my first question here.

I have a project written in PHP running on windows server and apache and mysql 8.
There is functionality to show news by tags (many-to many).

So I have three InnoDB tables:

news (id, title ...)
news_tag_assn (news_id, tag_id)
tag (id, name)

I use a query to filter news containing exactly two tags:

```
    SELECT news.* FROM news 
    INNER JOIN news_tag_assn ON news.id = news_tag_assn.news_id 
    INNER JOIN tag ON news_tag_assn.tag_id = tag.id 
    WHERE  (tag.name IN ('Corona', 'Egypt')) AND (news.category_id <> 14) AND (news.visible=1)
    GROUP BY news.id, news.category_id, news.visible 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
    ORDER BY news.created DESC, news.updated DESC LIMIT 5
```

I have created some indexes:

For news_tag_assn table:

- idx_news_tag_assn (news_id, tag_id)
- idx_tag_news_assn (tag_id, news_id)

For tag table:

- tag_id_name (id, name)

For news table:

- idx_news_visible_tags (id, category_id, visible)
- idx_cat_visible (category_id, visible)

After creating indexes query become faster (0.144ms vs > 1 sec.)

Another issue is counting news for pagination:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT news.* FROM news 
    INNER JOIN news_tag_assn ON news.id = news_tag_assn.news_id 
    INNER JOIN tag ON news_tag_assn.tag_id = tag.id 
    WHERE  (tag.name IN ('Corona', 'Egypt')) AND (news.category_id <> 14) AND (news.visible=1)
    GROUP BY news.id, news.category_id, news.visible 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 ) c
```

This query is slow than first in 2 times.

But i have a doubt that i have made all correctly. Maybe someone can advice something how can I make this query more fast.

**UPDATE**

*SHOW CREATE TABLE news:*

```
CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `alias` text,
  `short_description` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(765) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` longtext COMMENT,
  `label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `thumb` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int DEFAULT '1',
  `link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` int DEFAULT '0',
  `creator_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `layout` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `internal_layout` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `visible` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `custom_bundles` int DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`category_id`,`visible`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_news_visible_for_tags` (`id`,`category_id`,`visible`),
  KEY `idx_cat_visible` (`category_id`,`visible`),
  KEY `idx_date` (`created`,`updated`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22269 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

*SHOW CREATE TABLE news_tag_assn:*

```
CREATE TABLE `news_tag_assn` (
  `news_id` int NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`,`news_id`),
  KEY `idx_news_tag_assn` (`news_id`,`tag_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_tag_news_assn` (`tag_id`,`news_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

*SHOW CREATE TABLE tag:*

```
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `frequency` int DEFAULT '0',
  `visible` int DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`name`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tag_id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `tag_id_name` (`id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=156 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Short version of above: use EXPLAIN and consider using "USING INDEX ..." to use a specific index if MySQL is being inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your goal is to page through articles that are tagged with both Corona in Egypt?
- Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, not verbiage.  With the `SHOW`, I can see whether you have the optimal indexes.  (Hint:  [*Many-to-many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) )
- I have found that it is better to simply use the tag string instead of normalizing it to an ID.  This would eliminate the need for a many-to-many table, which is part of the performance problem.
- What table is `updated` in?  I can't optimize a query without knowing what table each column is in.
- After taking care of those, we can revisit whether the `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` pattern is optimal.
- You mentioned "pagination", but I don't see `OFFSET`.  Tip: [*Pagination*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/Pagination)

Tip:  Since the `PRIMARY KEY` of a table is an index (and `UNIQUE`), there is not need to have an index the same as the PK.  (Example: `idx_news_visible_for_tags`.)

Toss both of the `KEYs` of `tags` (but keep the `PRIMARY KEY`) and add `INDEX(name)`.  This may be the best performance improvement.

Comment: Thank you! I've updated question. I don't understand only - "What table is updated in? I can't optimize a query without knowing what table each column is in."

Comment: @demogorgorn - I can now see that the column `updated` lives in the table `news`.  I'll update your query.

Comment: And I added some tips to my Answer.